# SQL query from tkinter checkbotton

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to create an SQL query from tkinter's checkbutton. The number of criteria of the query depends on the number of checkboxes checked. Here is a first draft of the program :

```
class SearchPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        #Search bar
        self.entree = tk.Entry(self, text='', width=50)
        self.entree.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3)

        self.entree.bind("<Return>",self.search)

        search_button = tk.Button(self, text='Search',
                                  command=self.search)

        search_button.grid(row=0,column=3)

        #Search Card
        search_card_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        search_card_frame.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky='NW')

        search_card_label = tk.Label(search_card_frame, text='Search Card:', font=LARGE_FONT)
        search_card_label.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3,sticky='W')

        self.search_mode = ["Name","Types","Text"]
        self.search_var = {}
        self.search_button = {}
        for index,mode in enumerate(self.search_mode):
            self.search_var[mode] = tk.IntVar()
            self.search_button[mode] = tk.Checkbutton(search_card_frame, variable=self.search_var[mode],\
                                                        onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, text=mode)
            self.search_button[mode].grid(row=1,column=index)

        self.search_results = []

        self.search_results_list = tk.Listbox(self)#, width=30)
        self.search_results_list.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=4,sticky='nsew')

    def search(self, event=None):
        search_entree = self.entree.get()
        #card search query
        search_query = "SELECT name, type, text FROM cards WHERE "
        dict_mode = {"Name":"name", "Types": "type", "Text": "text"}
        for mode in self.search_mode:
            if self.search_var[mode].get() == 1:
                search_query += dict_mode[mode]+" LIKE '%"+search_entree+"%' OR "
        search_query = search_query[:-4]

        with sgbd.connect('AllPrintings.sqlite') as cnx:
            c = cnx.cursor()
            self.search_results = c.execute(search_query).fetchall()
```

My question is about the `search` function, is there a better way to build the SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use a list to store the `"xxxx LIKE '%yyyy%'"` and then join them using `" OR "` as separator and append the result to `search_query`:

```py
conditions = []  # store the LIKE clauses
for mode in self.search_mode:
    if self.search_var[mode].get() == 1:
        conditions.append(f"{dict_mode[mode]} LIKE '%{search_entree}%'")
search_query += " OR ".join(conditions)
```

Comment: Thank you, it's much better indeed !